# Hasura graphql query between dates

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, gql, hasura

In my hasura.io database, I have a `booking` table, where I store bookings with the following properties:

- id (autoincrement)
- from (timestamptz)
- to (timestamptz)
- description (text)

Now, from the UI, when a user makes a booking, I would like to check if there are any bookings made previously that touch the range of those dates.

eg. User wants to do a booking with the following dates:

```
{
  "from": "2020-03-31T14:00:00+00:00",
  "to": "2020-03-31T17:00:00+00:00"
}
```

But in the same date there is a booking:

```
{
  "from": "2020-03-31T15:00:00+00:00",
  "to": "2020-04-01T17:00:00+00:00"
}
```

> Notice, this booking is been made not within the range of the dates the user is trying to book. So the following query will return nothing.

```
query CheckBooking($from: timestamptz!, $to: timestamptz!) {
  booking(where: {_and: [{from: {_lte: $from}}, {to: {_gte: $to}}]}) {
    id
    from
    to
  }
}
```

This above is what I've tried without success.
Could anyone help to figure out what's the correct query to **check if there are any bookings in the range or within** the users new booking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We want to consider both `from` and `to` separately and apply a range to both. So you can do something like:

```
query CheckBooking($from: timestamptz!, $to: timestamptz!) {
  booking(where: {_or: [
    {_and: [{from: {_gte: $from}}, {from: {_lt: $to}}]},
    {_and: [{to: {_gt: $from}}, {to: {_lte: $to}}]},
  ]}) {
    id
    from
    to
  }
}
```